# What are the possible names of remote objects in a java rmi registry?

Tags: java, rmi

What are the possible names of remote objects in a java rmi registry? Are there forbidden characters?

I try to call the rebind method of the class Naming to bind an object in an rmi registry and I get a `MalformedUrlException`. I know that the problem is the name of the object because when I use a name like `abc` it works , so you probably don't need a stack trace to answer.

The thing is that the name is pseudorandomly generated.For example one of the names that caused the problem is `[B@f3d6a5`. Is there a way to use whatever name you like and if not then what are the permitted names?

This is strange because the api does not state any rules about the name ,you can see it [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/Naming.html#rebind%28java.lang.String,%20java.rmi.Remote%29). Maybe some characters that appear in the names ,like `[` , have to be escaped with `\`. Maybe it is not about java but about url specifications , if there are any , in which case I probably will have to use other names.

Comment: I just noticed in the stack trace that the illegal character is indeed "[".Still if you know a way around this or something I would like to see some answers.

Comment: Why are you using `toString()` results as bind names? And how is the client going to discover bind names that are generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API certainly doesn't say anything about restrictions, but if you get a `MalformedUrlException`, what I'd try is to [`URLEncode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) the randomly generated names.

Comment: Thanks!It works ,I checked the names in the registry by retrieving the list and I saw that the name with which the object is reffered to in the registry is the pseudorandom name that was generated in the beginning ,before the encoding ,so the encoding solves the problem without messing with the name that is finally used.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/Naming.html#rebind%28java.lang.String,%20java.rmi.Remote%29) state:

> name - a name in URL format (without
>   the scheme component)

If you take a look at the source code for `Naming` you will see that it converts thename you pass in into a `URI` and throws a `MalformedURLException` on certain conditions.

```
private static ParsedNamingURL intParseURL(String str)
    throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException
{
    URI uri = new URI(str);
    if (uri.isOpaque()) {
        throw new MalformedURLException(
        "not a hierarchical URL: " + str);
    }
    if (uri.getFragment() != null) {
        throw new MalformedURLException(
        "invalid character, '#', in URL name: " + str);
    } else if (uri.getQuery() != null) {
        throw new MalformedURLException(
        "invalid character, '?', in URL name: " + str);
    } else if (uri.getUserInfo() != null) {
        throw new MalformedURLException(
        "invalid character, '@', in URL host: " + str);
    }
```

This means that the name must be a valid `URI` and, an in addition, cannot contain `#`,`?` or `@`.

Take a look at the code yourself for more details.